# Primes generated from primes with given remainder

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

The following proposition seems true and is though related to but distinct from [Dirichlet theorem on primes in arithmetic progression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions). $p$ below is **prime** while the theorem allows $p$ to be arbitrary positive integers. How does one prove the following proposition?

Given two coprime positive integers $r<d$, there are infinitely many **primes** $p$ such that $pd+r$ are prime.

Comment: The simplest case is probably taking $r=1$ and $d=2$. Then the problem becomes: Are there infinite primes $p$ such that $2p+1$ is also prime? Those are called [Germain primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safe_and_Sophie_Germain_primes) and the question is open even for that case.

Comment: There is no pair $(r,d)$ of positive integers for which it is known that there are infinite many primes $p$ such that $pd+r$ is also prime. If $r$ and $d$ are coprime ($r<d$ is not necessary) , Dixon's conjecture implies this is the case.